# is it "likely become" or "likely to become"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I have recently encountered both while reading articles, can anyone clarify which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct.  *Become* can be used as the primary verb or as an infinitive.

Examples of the use of *become* as a primary verb are

> He becomes agitated when the music plays.
>
> He will become agitated when the music plays.
>
> He will likely become agitated when the music plays.

In the last two examples, *become* is the primary verb, and *will* is an auxilliary verb forming the future tense.

As an infinitive

> He starts to become agitated as the music plays.
>
> He is going to become agitated when the music plays.
>
> He is likely to become agitated when the music plays.

In these cases, *become* is not the primary verb. Rather, it is used as an object of the primary verbs, *starts, is going* and *is*.

As noted in the comment by @Hellion below, both constructions have the same meaning.

Comment: And both have the same meaning, it's worth mentioning.  The other answers so far attempt to draw a distinction between the two that I don't believe exists.

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct.

When you are talking in a future context about something that you are very sure of you will use *likely become*:

> He will **likely become** a great actor.

When you are talking or discussing the possibility of something happening you will use *likely to become*

> He is **likely to become** a great actor.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely both are correct, Use of difference is :

`likely to become` shows expectations/predictions.
**example** : Children who get sexually abuses are likely to become frustrated.

`likely become` is surety.
**example** : Broken marriages likely become hell.